# Similar matrices and the trace

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, then
$trace(A) = trace(B).$

By the definition of trace, I can see that there exists an invertible
matrix $Q$ such that $A = Q^{-1}BQ.$ Thus, for this particular matrix $Q$,
$$trace(A) = trace(Q^{-1}BQ).$$

However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to make
$trace(Q^{-1}BQ) = trace(B).$ Are there particular properties of the trace
that I need to consider to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important property of traces is that for any matrices $X$ and $Y$ we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}\trace(XY)=\trace(YX)\tag{1}
$$
So, if $A=PBP^{-1}$, then
\begin{align*}
\trace(A)
&=\trace\left(PBP^{-1}\right)\\
&=\trace\left((PB)P^{-1}\right)\\
&=\trace\left(P^{-1}(PB)\right)\\
&=\trace\left(\left(P^{-1}P\right)B\right)\\
&=\trace(IB)\\
&=\trace(B)
\end{align*}
Note that (1) is proved by 
\begin{align*}
\trace(XY) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^n[XY]_{kk} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n[X]_{kl}[Y]_{lk} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n[Y]_{lk}[X]_{kl} \\
&= \sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n[Y]_{lk}[X]_{kl} \\
&= \sum_{l=1}^n[YX]_{ll} \\
&= \trace(YX)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\mbox{tr }Q^{-1}BQ = \sum_i \delta_{ik} (\sum_{j,n}Q_{ij}^{-1}B_{jn}Q_{nk})
= \sum_i (\sum_{j,n}Q_{ij}^{-1}B_{jn}Q_{ni}) = \sum_{j,n}B_{jn}\sum_i Q_{ni}Q_{ij}^{-1} 
$$

By the definition of matrix inverse,
$$
\sum_i Q_{ni}Q_{ij}^{-1} =\delta_{nj}
$$
so
$$\mbox{tr}Q^{-1}BQ =\sum_{j,n}B_{jn} \delta_{nj} = \sum_j B_jj = \mbox{tr } B
$$